# ¿Cómo puedo saber la diferencia en milisegundos entre dos fechas usando la clase Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel-5, datetime, carbon

Queria realizar una prueba unitaria donde comparara el tiempo de respuesta de dos funciones y comprobara que uno fuera mas rapida que la otra. He visto que con la clase \Datetime se puede hacer haciendo lo siguiente

```
$a = new \Datetime();
sleep(1);
$b = new \Datetime();
$diff = $b->format('U')-$a->format('U');
```

Esto me devuelve 1 ya que puse a esperar por 1 seg, pero lo que necesito es en milisegundos. Con Carbon seria algo como esto

```
$a = Carbon\Carbon::now();
sleep(1);
$b = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$diff = $b->diff($a);
echo $diff->s;
```

Pero me sucede lo mismo me devuelve una instancia de DateInterval el cual solo posee como minima expresión los segundos. Carbon solo posee funciones como Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds() que no resuelven mi problema. Tal ves exista otra para los milisegundos y no me haya dado cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que `DateTime` tenga en cuenta los Microsegundos debes iniciar la instancia con ellos, de lo contrario no los tendrá encuenta.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE));
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    // tiempo ejecución 100 ciclos
}
$b = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE));
$diff = $b->format('U.u')-$a->format('U.u');
echo 'Tiempo ejecución 100 ciclos: '.number_format($diff, 10);
```

También puedes utilizar directamente [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php)

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    // tiempo ejecución 100 ciclos
}
$time_end = microtime(true);
$diff = $time_end - $time_start;
echo 'Tiempo ejecución 100 ciclos: '.number_format($diff, 10);
```

En la documentación de [date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) vemos:

> NOTA: Microsegundos (añadido en PHP 5.2.2). Observe que date() siempre generará 000000 ya que toma un parámetro de tipo integer, mientras que DateTime::format() admite microsegundos si DateTime fue creado con microsegundos.